# sshfs appears to mount, but ls & cp on local mount-point hang?

Tags: mount, manjaro, sshfs, fuse, smartcard

I am FUSE mounting a remote FreeBSD machine with

> `sudo sshfs -C user@remote-ip:/home/user/ /mnt/localmnt/ -o allow_other -o SmartcardDevice=/dev/hidraw7`

to authenticate via an OpenPGP smartcard device. I've tried this as both root and non-root users. This ties up standard input instead of returning to shell like a regular `mount` command, but the output of `mount` shows it is mounted:

> `user@remote-ip:/home/user/ on /mnt/freebsd type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)`

I've removed `default_permissions` per [Mount with sshfs and write file permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222944/mount-with-sshfs-and-write-file-permissions).

Unfortunately `sudo ls` and `sudo cp` hang on the local mount-point, without any error output in `dmesg`. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question started with trying to authenticate `sshfs` with an OpenPGP smartcard, then was edited to its current form when I thought authentication was solved.

My current problem was using `-o SmartcardDevice=/dev/hidraw7`, which started because otherwise I was getting a password prompt from the remote host. (Users have passwords disabled and are setup for key authentication only.)

My initial problem was caused by running `sudo sshfs`, but I'm not sure why this is. Running `sshfs` as a non-root user and *also* omitting `SmartcardDevice` correctly prompts for smart-card PIN authentication, then mounts as expected with all local utilities working.